# BottomAppBar backgrounTint is not correctly match to parent and showing in half of screen

Tags: java, android, android-bottomappbar

i try my layout code and the BottomAppBar is not showing perfectly i search everywhere but found no question about it.

[image]
i tried this on Android Studio 3.4 my gradle dependencies are

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

}
```

Code i use in home_bottomappbar.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:fabAttached="true"
            app:fabCradleDiameter="0dp"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp" />
     <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you can add the screenshot if there is rendering issue, it will help collaborators to understand the issue without reading the entire post.

Comment: Thanks for answering i have added the  Screeshot link. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Coordinator` layout with `Relative` or `Liner` Layout. It will work fine.

Comment: LinearLayout or Rellative also not working. I don't know why that code is not work in this project. it working perfect in my other projects

Comment: avoid using the `coordinator` layout in nested layouts, your `coordinator` layout should be parent/root layout and set layout anchors.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem for a while too

The solution is to change the **width** of the **BottomAppBar** to **fill_parent**, it should work fine now :)